# Problem with voice responses in dialogflow cx

Tags: bots, dialogflow-cx, genesys

I have a problem with Dialogflow CX. I have created a bot for chat and voice, with dialogflow using nodejs.

In chat it works very well, the answers are fast, but in voice the answers take a long time, sometimes up to a minute, as if the voice processing is slow.

I have tried with different flows, even making them very simple, and in all of them the same thing happens, the problem only occurs with voice. I have also changed the voice.

The connection is made through genesys cloud.